# validating multiple TinyMCE Editor

Tags: jquery, validation, tinymce

I have a form with multiple TinyMCE editors. Some of the editors are advance and some are simple editors. I have used [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for validation in client-side. I have been validating single TinyMCE editor by adding following code.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

    var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); // get the content

    $('#description').val(content); // put it in the textarea

});
```

But now i am supposed to validate all editors, any idea??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

  for (i=0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++){
    var content = tinymce.editors[i].getContent(); // get the content

    $('#description').val(content); // put it in the textarea
  }
});
```

or easier

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
     tinymce.triggerSave();
});
```

Comment: This is some what i am looking for.. but in this code also the content of each editor is put into `description` can we somehow get the corresponding textarea's id, so that we put the content from editor to it's corresponding textarea.

Comment: you can get the editorids (they equal the textarea ids) using tinymce.editors[i].id

Comment: to put the content from editor to it's corresponding textarea you may also use tinymce.triggerSave() once to do this for all tinymce editors!

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Comment: Mind his deliberate error after for i=0 
it should be semi colon not comma

Answer (score 4):

A more generic approach is to to save the editor contents back to the textarea and then let jquery validation do it's magic in the textarea itself

```
tinymce.init({
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init change', function () {
            editor.save();
        });
    }
});
```

Because the tinymce textarea is hidden you have to also update your jquery validation code to something like this

```
$('#myform').validate({
    ignore: ':hidden:not(textarea)'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like that

java script code

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
        });
```

Html code

First TinyMCE

```
 <textarea rows="" cols="" id="first" class="validate[required] text-input tinymce"></textarea>
```

Second First TinyMCE

```
<textarea rows="" cols="" id="second" class="validate[required] text-input tinymce"></textarea>
```

i also used like that, it's working fine me

Comment: It validates the editors but not validating properly as in other form elements. My problem is submit button in needed to click twice to get the response... it has to give the response on first click as in other form elements validation...

Answer (score 0):

f you have Html editor tinymce the required validation is not working ok, you can use this code to solve your problem,
install tinymce in your application 
if you have more than one Htmleditor you can do this 
i know this is proper solution but you can do it and solve this problem

In model give the path of tinymce.cshtml page ok

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter About Company")]
  [Display(Name = "About Company : ")]
  [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
  public string txtAboutCompany { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter About Company")]
  [Display(Name = "About Company : ")]
  [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
  public string txtAboutCompany { get; set; }
```

Now in your view add one span like this

```
 <div class="divclass">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany, new { @class = "required" })
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany)
     <span class="field-validation-error" id="AC" style="margin:9px 0 0 157px;"></span>
 </div>
<div class="divclass">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany, new { @class = "required" })
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany)
     <span class="field-validation-error" id="AC" style="margin:9px 0 0 157px;"></span>
 </div>
```

Create jQuery on submit button click event

```
$("#BusinessProfile").click(function () {
    var aboutC = $("#txtAboutCompany").val()
    var pinfo = $("#txtProductinfo").val();
    if (aboutC == "" && pinfo == "") {
        $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
        $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
        $("#bpform").valid();
        return false;
    } else if (aboutC == "") {
        $("#PI").append("").val("").html("")
        $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
        $("#txtAboutCompany").focus();
        $("#bpform").valid();
        return false;
    } else if (pinfo == "") {
        $("#AC").append("").val("").html("")
        $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
        $("#txtProductinfo").focus();
        $("#bpform").valid();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $("#AC").append("").val("").html("");
        $("#PI").append("").val("").html("");
        //return true;
        $("#bpform").validate();
    }
});
```

i hope your problem may be solve

Answer (score 0):

jquery validation has two problems with tinyMCE editors in my experience. First, tinyMCE buffers content so the underlying textarea conent which jquery validation sees is not always reflective of the editor. Second, the textarea found by jquery validation is hidden several levels deep in the tinyMCE structure. When jquery validation places its error message after that textarea, the error message is hidden as well.

There are two separate jquery validation features that can resolve these issues:
[Normalizers](https://jqueryvalidation.org/normalizer/): allow you to transform the contents of a field before validation
[Error Placement](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/): allows you to modify where the error is displayed in the DOM. Both of these can be configured globally through the setDefaults method as such:

```
 jQuery.validation.setDefaults({
    normalizer:function(val){
        var ele = jQuery(this);
        if(window.tinyMCE.editors[ele.id]){
            window.tinyMCE.editors[ele.id].save();
            return window.tinyMCE.editors[ele.id].getContents();
        }
        return val;
    },
    errorPlacement:function(error,element)
    {
        var ele = jQuery(element);
        if(window.tinyMCE.editors[ele.id]){
            var realTarget = window.tinyMCE.editors[ele.id].getContainer().parent();
            error.insertAfter(realTarget);
        }
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead you could use TinyMCE's `isDirty()` method

Ref: [Here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.isDirty)

**Usage**

> tinyMCE.activeEditor.isDirty()

Hope this helps